# Do all authors contribute to a reviewer response or only the main authors?

Tags: peer-review

I would like to know if all authors contribute to the reviewer response document for first revision, or do only the main authors contribute?

Comment: Thank you. This is my first paper.i have no idea how it will work.

Comment: What does your advisor says about this question?

Comment: What is a "main author"?

Comment: i mean the First author

Comment: I edited to remove second question about length of the reviewer response document. It's a separate issue. Feel free to ask as separate question.

Comment: Thank you, but my first question was about the response on reviewer comments   it self and not just document. Since we will have few days bfr the second submission.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The authors can arrange this however they want. If they all want to work on it actively, that's fine. If they'd rather agree to have one person write the response and then send it to the other authors for approval, that's fine too. All that matters is that everyone approves. Unlike the paper itself, it's not necessary that all authors make a significant contribution.

It's impossible to give any general advice on length: in some cases a short response is sufficient, in other cases you might have to write more to express what you need to say. But conciseness is generally desirable; nobody likes to read unnecessary text that doesn't add anything.